# filter array to get row with maximum value of column in 2-d array GoogleScripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a 2d array - rows and columns from spreadsheet. I want to filter it and get a row where specific column (8) has a maximum value.

I try to apply this

```
 const filteredRow= fullArray.filter(r => r[7] === Math.max(r[7]))
```

but it does not give the desired output

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)  instead:

```
const max7r = fullArray.reduce((r1,r2) => r1[7]>r2[7] ? r1:r2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that in this case, when at first, the maximum value is retrieved, your script can be used.

#### From:

```
const filteredRow= fullArray.filter(r => r[7] === Math.max(r[7]))
```

#### To:

```
const max = Math.max.apply(null, fullArray.map(r => r[7]));
const filteredRow = fullArray.filter(r => r[7] === max);
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, when there are several maximum values as the same value, `filteredRow` has the several rows.

#### Reference:

- [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)